# Screen freezes in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, freeze, asus

After hours of searching I just couldn't find a decent answer to the problem I am facing with my system, so I'm hoping one of you guys could help me out here.

I have an Asus N76VM laptop with nvidia GeForce 630M (drivers installed from nvidia, version 319), 8 GB ram, 2,5 GHz x4 intel i5, with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed.

Every once in a while and it seems completely random to me, the screen freezes. The solution to this problem was pressing ctrl+alt+f2 after freezing, followed by ctrl+alt+f7.

Now this solves the problem for me, but I am looking for a more permanent solution and I was hoping one of you guys could help me out with this.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

*[EDIT]*

Ok, so after searching a lot on the web for this issue, it seemed that the amount of people reporting this issue was almost as large as the different problems causing the freezing screen issue. I tried a lot of things to make it go away and ended up with a system that didn't function how it should any more.

I completely reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but this time without the Nvidia drivers. As expected there were no screen freezes anymore and everyone was happy.

Now I want my Nvidia card to run sometimes when running programs that need more graphic processing power. I stumbled across Bumblebee and installed everything according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

After this I still received the following message when I type ¨optirun glxspheres¨ in the terminal:

[ 2019.967042] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) No devices detected.

[ 2019.967105] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

For this problem there are just too many solutions, and n00by as I am, there is no way to get my head around this to solve it properly. I did install the latest kernel version as my last attempt to solve the problem.

[EDIT 3-11-2013]

Can someone please help me with just the nvidia/bumblebee issue? I'm searching the net and trying sollutions for the past 5 days now and itś starting to give me headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issues I had as described in my question. Following the directions from the following link http://orkultus.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/how-to-nvidia-319-12-drivers-in-ubuntu-based-systems-with-bumblebee/ and after that configuring the */etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf* file like so:

```
## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia

[driver-nvidia]

# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-331
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

After that i changed the */etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia* file

```
#"BusID PCI:01:00:0"
```

to

```
BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
```

After everything, how could something so small cost me so much time! I hope anyone learns from my experience :)