# Graphic drivers for Asus N76VZ (NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I just installed the latest Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm trying to figure out what drivers I should install and how to do it. I have an integrated Intel GPU and a Nvidia GeForce GT 650M that should work together according to the Optimus technology. The software updater doesn't show any additional third-party driver available, though, and this makes me think that maybe there are no drivers for Linux 3.11 yet.
So the question is: do I have to install additional drivers over the ones preinstalled by the system? If yes, where can I find them?

Thank you and please forgive the mistakes I could have done, but I'm completely new to Linux and I'm trying to get started..

Comment: I think there are libraries filled with books about this issue. There is a huge post committed about nVidia & Linux found here http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work

Comment: Thanks. Since I have Windows and Ubuntu in dual-boot and I primarily use Windows, I don't care if Optimus isn't supported by Linux, but the nVidia GPU always on causes the laptop to overheat and drain the battery terribly fast. Is there a SECURE method to disable it ONLY in Ubuntu leaving it enabled in Windows?

Comment: I think you should realy consider using bumblebee. This program disables your graphics optimus card and enables it only when you specificaly request using the card through the `optirun` command. The solution that did the trick for me was this http://askubuntu.com/questions/367726/screen-freezes-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: By the way I use an Asus N76VM with geforce gt 630m so we have pretty similar configuration of conputer

Comment: Also, for better battery management, download TLP after configuring bumblebee